# Does TC server has EJB support

Tags: rest, jboss, ejb, tcserver

We have an application in JBOSS. The application has a jar which has an abstract class and the class uses EJB. One of the classes is extending that abstract class. The application works fine in JBOSS and it is a SOAP service application.

I need to migrate that application in TC server. I am putting a REST layer using Spring and Jersey on top of that application. **I am unable to instantiate the class which extends the abstract class** in JBOSS application. I did some research but could not get a right answer and not sure if EJB is supported in TC server. The error I am getting is

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJBObject
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat (which Spring TC server essentially is) is a pure servlet container, it does not have EJB support.